# What does this capistrano error mean when doing an AWS file fetch via cap tasks?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, capistrano, capistrano3

In my deploy/development.rb, I have the following line:-

```
set :env_path, 's3api get-object --bucket <bucket_name> --key <file_name> <file_name>'
```

In my cap file, I have the following task defined:

```
task :download_configs do
            on roles(:all) do
                    within release_path do
                            execute :aws, "#{fetch(:env_path)}"
                    end
            end
           # on roles(:db) do
           #        within release_path do
           #                execute :aws, "#{fetch(:env_path)}"
           #        end
           # end
end
```

But on cap deploy,I am seeing the following errors:-

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@54.213.226.117: aws exit status: 1
aws stdout: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 15, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 30, in <module>
    from awscli.help import ProviderHelpCommand
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/help.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils.core import publish_string
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/core.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils import frontend, io, utils, readers, writers
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/frontend.py", line 41, in <module>
    import docutils.utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import docutils.io
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/io.py", line 18, in <module>
    from docutils.utils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/utils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in <module>
    locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/locale.py", line 556, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/locale.py", line 484, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
aws stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: aws exit status: 1
aws stdout: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 15, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 30, in <module>
    from awscli.help import ProviderHelpCommand
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/help.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils.core import publish_string
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/core.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils import frontend, io, utils, readers, writers
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/frontend.py", line 41, in <module>
    import docutils.utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import docutils.io
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/io.py", line 18, in <module>
    from docutils.utils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docutils/utils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in <module>
    locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/locale.py", line 556, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/locale.py", line 484, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
aws stderr: Nothing written
```

Please help me identify what is going wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark (I'm not a Python dev), but you might be able add the following to `deploy.rb`:

```
set :default_env, { 
  'LANG' => 'en_US.UTF-8'
}
```

Derived mostly from https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5420#issuecomment-154454607

I would check to see if you can run the command manually on the server. If you cannot, then figure out how to without Capistrano. If you can, perhaps see if there is some configuration in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` that can be added to the Capistrano config.